# Open Mapping Theorem and Continuity

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ $\ne$ const be holomorphic in $D$ $\subset$ $C$ is open and connected. Prove that the image $f(D)$ is open and connected.

What if in the above statement, we replace the word "holomorphic" with the word "continuous", can we guarantee that $f(D)$ is open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The continuous image of a connected set is connected but the continuous image of an open set need not be open in general.

Consider for instance the image of $(-1,1)$ by $f(x):=x^2$ is $ [0,1)$,  which is not open.

**Moral :**
Holomorphicity is a lot to ask of a function (much much more than continuity) but in return we obtain some very nice results such as the Open Mapping Theorem which in turn leads to Maximum Modulus Principle.

Comment: Correct. I edited.

Answer (score 0):

No, take $D = D(0,2\pi)$ and $f(z) = \sin(|z|)$. Then $f(D) =[-1,1]$ that is clearly not open